# Want to convert proper JSON request in AXIOS ReactJs to send to django

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, django, axios

My payload is in string form as below:

```js
payload= "[{"message":"message text", "id":1, "code":0}, {"message":"message text", "id":2, "code":1}, {"message":"message text", "id":3, "code":0}]"
```

I am getting the pay load from query string.

ex = https:\xyz.com\endpoint?payload=[{"message":"message text", "id":1, "code":0}, {"message":"message text", "id":2, "code":1}, {"message":"message text", "id":3, "code":0}]

`JSON.stringify(payload)` does not help here as it is a string and `JSON.parse(payload)` throws error.

the axios request is as below:

```
  try {
    const response = await axiosInstance.post('/postenpoint/', payload,
      { headers: authHeader });
    return response;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  };
```

is there any inbuilt function or effective way in JS other than string parsing in such case?

The problem is at backend which is developed using django gets the response as `{'[{"message":"message text", "id":1, "code":0}, {"message":"message text", "id":2, "code":1}, {"message":"message text", "id":3, "code":0}]': ''}`

This must go as proper json form instead it' goin as a key only.

Comment: Your string is already JSON

Comment: also tried JSON.parse. non of them help.

Comment: Where does this `payload` come from? How are you trying to use it with Axios?

Comment: I am parsing QUERY string and getting the payload.

Answer (score 1):

Use `JSON.parse`:

```
JSON.parse(payload)
```

Comment: have edited the question. kindly go through is once again.